# change image in a div with any effect like fadein when mouse hovered on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below shown is the format of my html code. In the header div i have a image. Each box(box1, box2, box3) inside the contain div has link inside like(software development(box1), Graphic Designing(box2), and Technical Training(box3). These links when clicked will take me to  separate pages which has their own header images. So i have 3 header image for each box and a default header image in the home page.In the home page when ever I hover my mouse in the box1 div the header image should change to the box1 header image with an effect like fadeIn and return my default image on mouse  out. Same for box2 and box3. Please help me with doing this with CSS or JS or jQuery. Thank You

```
<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="out">
         <div class="in">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div class="contain">
               <div class="box1"></div>
               <div class="box2"></div>
               <div class="box3"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 100%
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
}
.out{
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 730px;
    border-top: 5px solid  #333333;
}
.in{
    width: 900px;
    height: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#header{
    background:url(../img/Untitled-1.jpg);
    height: 175px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.contain{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 428px;
}
.box1{
    height: 360px;
    width: 295px;
    float: left;
    margin: 67px 0px 0px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e6e7e9;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #735d8c;
}
.box2{
    height: 360px;
    width: 295px;
    float: left;
    margin: 67px 0px 0px 302px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e6e7e9;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #735d8c;
}
.box3{
    height: 360px;
    width: 295px;
    float: left;
    margin: 67px 0px 0px 602px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #e6e7e9;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #735d8c;
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. You'll have to use javascript/jQuery to do this.

Comment: Actually i dont know js and jquery. Im a beginner for web development. So I have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: Learn to format your code and show where you left with your JS. Respect the edits, and show some effort.

Comment: I am sorry for that. I dint know as im new. Will learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/olehuz/3/edit)*

jQuery:

```
var currPage = 0; // PLAY HERE: set here current page (0 = home)

var $header = $('#header');
var $headerImg = $header.find('img');

$headerImg.eq( currPage ).show().addClass('currentImg');

// clone images to boxes:
var c = 0;
$('.box').each(function( i ){

  $(this).prepend( $headerImg.eq(i==currPage? (i+1+c++) : c+i).clone() );
});


$('.box img[class^=headImg]').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
  
  var opacity = e.type=='mouseenter' ? 1 : 0 ;
  var myClass = $(this).prop('class'); // get class  
  var $mainImg = $header.find('img.'+myClass);
  
  
  $headerImg.hide();
  $mainImg.stop().fadeTo(300, opacity);
  $('.currentImg').stop().fadeTo(600, !opacity);
   
  
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="out">

     <div class="in">
       
        <div id="header">
          <img class="headImg1" src="home.jpg" alt="" />
          <img class="headImg2" src="ONE.jpg" alt="" />
          <img class="headImg3" src="TWO.jpg" alt="" />
          <img class="headImg4" src="THREE.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
       
        <div class="contain">
           <div class="box">
          
          </div>
           <div class="box">
          
          </div>
           <div class="box">
          
          </div>
        </div>
       
     </div>
    
    
  </div>
 </div>
```

MODIFIED CSS PART:

```
/*ADDED*/
#header img{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}


.contain{
    margin: 0px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 428px;
}
.box{ /* CHANGED */
    height: 360px;
    width: 294px;
    float: left;
    margin: 67px 3px 0px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #e6e7e9;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #735d8c;
}

/* ADDED */
.box img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: @Kowshik you're welcome. If you need some code clarification I'll be happy to explain

Comment: I need a change in this..!!...here the image that im inserting in the header is cloned to all the three boxes. I need the hover class to be the box itself and no need to clone the images. When I hover on box1, box2, box3 i need the respective  images to be displayed in the header section.hope you got it. Im ready to explain if you dint.:)

Answer (score 1):

I have a made an [BIN](http://jsbin.com/ilawuj/4/)

I am placing same image for all the 3 divs like

```
  $('#content,#content2,#content3').mouseover(function(){

$('#header').css('background','url(http://www.google.com/mobile/android/images/android.jpg)')

});
```

You change with your respective images like

```
 $('#content').mouseover(function(){

$('#header').css('background','url(http://www.google.com/mobile/android/images/android.jpg)')

});

 $('#content2').mouseover(function(){

$('#header').css('background','url(http://www.google.com/mobile/android/images/android.jpg)')

});....
```

Answer (score 0):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/xTjQT/2/

```
 $('a').mouseover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('alt');
alert(src);
$('#header img').stop().fadeOut(100, function() {
     $(this).attr('src', src);
     $(this).fadeIn(100);
});
});

$('a').mouseout(function() {
$('#header img').stop().fadeOut(200, function() {
     $(this).attr('src', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
     $(this).fadeIn(100);
});
});
```